# Run as administrator not showing in start menu

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7

**Background:**
My C++ application developed by VS2008 and use the VS setup project to create installer for that. After installation it will create two shortcuts to application. one is in user desktop and second one is in start menu. Application(myApp.exe) installed to the `Program files` directory.

**Question:** If I right click on the icons in the start menu, there is a option `Run as Administrator` for most of them. But if I right click on the shortcut that related to my application. It doesn't show `Run as Administrator`. How to fix this?

**Edit:** But if i right click on the `myApp.exe` in the `Program files`, it shows "Run as Administrator".

Comment: The shortcut on the desktop doesn't show "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: I believe anything you compile with VS 2008 should have a manifest (probably embedded into the exe itself). The manifest tell the OS the program needs (or wants) to run as administrator. The check box is (at least primarily) for programs that don't have a manifest.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes, the shortcut in the desktop also doesn't show "Run as Administrator"

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I checked and exe file embedded with a manifest file. How can manage to show "Run as Administrator" using manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this after so much testing and searching. So here I mention it for  use of any one.

- Windows only shows `Run as Administrator` in the context menu for that shortcuts those are directly targeting to some `exe` file.
- If you use VS deployment (setup) project to create your installation with desktop and start menu shortcuts. Those shortcuts not targeting to `exe` (Application.exe) file.
- Instead of that shortcuts targeting to application folder (MS office 2007 also same). This is called  `installation-on-demand and advertisement`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the more details.
- This will help your application to repair from file missing (pray Google for more).
- So we have to disable this feature if you want to target your shortcuts directly to exe file.
- For this you can use command prompt or some tool. here is how to do it.

  1. Nirmally windows installer having a `exe` and a `msi`.
  2. These setting are stored at at `msi` generated with setup file.
  3. So You have to alter the file and add the entry [`DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to property table.

**Using Command prompt:**

`msiexec /i <path to your msi> DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1`

**Using [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx) Tool:**(Meny other tools also there)

1. Download Orca tool from [here](http://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor.html) and install it.
2. Right click your `*.msi` file and click `edit with orca`.
3. Go to property table and add new entry `DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS` and value is `1` , save and close.
4. Now you done.
5. Install using setup.exe file and check the target of the shortcuts. those are directly target to the `exe` file in application folder.
6. Now if you right click on the shortcuts those shows `Run as Administrator` option in context menu.

**Note:** Doing this you will gain `Run as Administrator` but scarify the `windows auto repair` capability.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file there is option "requestedExecutionLevel" and "UIAccess" which will manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Set your embedded manifest to require administrator. On the project property page:

[image]

...on the (highlighted) `UAC Execution Level`, change `asInvoker` to `requireAdministrator`. Build your project to embed the new manifest, and it should be ready to do its thing.

Oh -- I didn't think to do it here, but in the `Configuration` drop-down, you probably want to select `All Configurations`, instead of the (default) `Active` configuration that's selected in the screen shot. Gets seriously annoying -- you think you've got things fixed, then you change to "Release" and a bunch of stuff suddenly breaks, and you have to go through figuring out what you'd changed, and edit those changes into the `Release` configuration as well.

Comment: But he doesn't want to *require* administrative privileges. This option will automatically request elevation at startup. He just wants the option to be available in the context menu.

Comment: @CodyGray: At least as I read it, he *does* want it to run as administrator -- just right now, he's trying to do that with post-installation adjustments, where this handles it automatically at build time.

Comment: This solution doesn't works for me. With above change menifest file newly included `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>` but context menu same as before.

Comment: And actually I no need to run my application as administrator always. If user need, there should be a way to 'run as administrator'. Anyway than you so much for the help!

Comment: In that case, although I haven't tested it, I'd *expect* to get what you want by changing "Generate Manifest" to "no".