# Why windows installer shortcut targeting to "application folder" not to "application"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

If I include start menu or desktop short with visual studio setup project.The shortcuts target location will be the the `application folder` not the `application` (Application.exe). Why specially windows installer does this. (check the MS office start menu shortcut).

I'm facing some troubling with this. Because shorts context menu shows `Run as Administrator` if that targeting to `exe` only. So the shortcuts create using windows installer does not shows `Run As Administrator` because it targets to application folder. I used VS 2008 to create the setup project.

Comment: Your setup project's settings are incorrect. You forgot to post them, though.

Comment: @CodeGray: Which setting you mean? Shortcut only has `target ` setting related to this. I think this is common issue. you may read this thread to understand http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/7fc429ae-6d3e-4388-8ed4-a7f0b53fe580/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is question related to my previous question and the answer I found relevant to this question also. So I recommend to read my the answer at bellow link if anyone face this issue.

[Run as administrator not showing in start menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228448/run-as-administrator-not-showing-in-start-menu/16232580#16232580)